# I get "NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location" error when trying to push a route with a query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a navigation header, which contains a search bar that redirects the user to the home view with the search bar value as a query, like this:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="search-by-query">
        <input type="text" :model="searchQuery">
        <div @click="search()">Search</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import router from "../router"

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            searchQuery: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        search(){
            router.push({ name: "home", query: { searchQuery: this.query }})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when I execute that function from inside the `home` view, I get this error `"NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location"`. I understand that I'm getting the error because I'm trying to go to the same route, but I'm not sure how else I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround the error with `.catch`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    search() {
      this.$router.push(...).catch(() => { /* ignore */ })
    }
  }
}
```

Or by using a `router-link` in the template:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'home', query: { searchQuery: query } }">Search</router-link>
```

Note your question shows the `data` prop named `searchQuery`, but you're referring to it as `query` in `router.push()`.